# Input separated by "/" for two different variables

Tags: java

The following is a section from my code

```
System.out.print("Input date (mm-dd-yy): ");
int month,day,year;
System.out.println(month+"/"+day+"/"+year);
```

Is there a way if I input:

```
Input date (mm-dd-yy): 1-2-2000
```

For the output to be:

```
1/2/2000
```

So that the value '1' represents the month, '2' represents the day, and '2000' represents the year?

Comment: [`String#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) and [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) are probably going to be in your future

Answer (score 0):

Is that so?

```
System.out.print("Input date (mm-dd-yy): ");
String str = new Scanner(System.in).next();
String[] date = str.split("-");
System.out.println(date[0] + "/" + date[1] + "/" + date[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the solution of your problem, using C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template<class Type>
void showContentContainer(Type& input)
{
    for(int i=0; i<input.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<input[i];
    }
    return;
}
void dfs(int current, int previous, vector<int>& visited, string& input)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    if(input[current]=='-')
    {
        input[current]='/';
    }
    for(int next=(current+1); next<input.size(); ++next)
    {
        if(next==previous)
        {
            continue;
        }
        dfs(next, current, visited, input);
    }
    if(current==0)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"inputString <- ";
        showContentContainer(input);
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    string inputString;
    cin>>inputString;
    cout<<"inputString <- ";
    showContentContainer(inputString);
    vector<int> visited(3, 0);
    dfs(0, -1, visited, inputString);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1-2-2000
```

Here is the result:

```
1/2/2000
```